# Is there an alternative to this Oracle cursor query perhaps concatenating the fields into a Varchar field/blob?

Tags: json, oracle, cursor

I have some queries that are fed into a program that parses data. Unfortunately, cursor queries are not being read by the program. Is there a fancy alternative to a query such as the below, where the cursor can be avoided and a varchar/blob field can store the structure of the nested data in json format?

```
SELECT department_name, CURSOR(SELECT salary, commission_pct 
   FROM employees e
   WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id)
   FROM departments d
   ORDER BY department_name;
```

Thank you.

Comment: And you want to store the JSON data into DB? or trying to retrieve it? Storing JSON structure is something against the Relational Model, and most of the traditional SQL developers would hate.

Answer (score 2):

Simple Solution could be

```
SELECT children(d.department_name,d.department_id)
   FROM departments d
   ORDER BY department_name;
```

And the function having this query inside, returns the resultset completely as a String concatenated in JSON fashion, grouping all employees.(FOR LOOP)

```
SELECT salary, commission_pct 
   FROM employees e
   WHERE e.department_id = :input_department_id
```

Return it as CLOB object.

Edit: An Excellent [Example](http://ora-00001.blogspot.in/2010/02/ref-cursor-to-json.html) here, should help you a lot.